# Warn user of unsaved changes in Angular 10

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have angular application with angular reactive forms. I want to warn users when closing the browser tab/window based on some condition.

How do I achieve that?

I tried the following but it always shows the warning message regardless of what I return or what condition I use.
I have the following in the component.ts file:

```
@HostListener('window:unload', ['$event']) handleClose($event: Event) {
  $event.returnValue = false;
  if (!this.myForm.pristine) {
    $event.preventDefault();
  return false;
  }
  else return true;
```

}

And the following in the component.html file

```html
<div (window:beforeunload)="handleClose($event)"></div>
```

What I want to do is check for a condition to show/not show the warning pop up.
Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
@HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event'])
handleClose($event): void {
  if (!this.myForm.pristine) { // prevent unload event action.
    $event.returnValue = true;
  }
}
```